# Is the file current.mof a bottleneck when using the DSC module?

Tags: powershell, puppet, dsc

The msutter DSC module (PowerShell Defined State Configuration) seems to have a bottleneck. Every class that uses a DSC resource generates intermediate Powershell/DSC code that creates a file called current.mof in the same directory. When I run **Puppet agent --test** things go screwy. It seems like one puppet class is getting information related to a different puppet class, as if it generates its MOF and then executes a different class' MOF by accident. I suppose I can find a way to chain all these resource together with dependency arrows so that they are executed serially, but then that means I can't have truly separate profile classes for each ZIP archive I am unpacking. I would prefer for one server to get classes A, B, and C, another gets B, C, etc. If I put the chaining in, then I have to duplicate a lot of code.

Am I correct about this? I am very new to PowerShell. Here is an example of a single class that pulls a ZIP file from a Web Service and then unzips it into the target location:

```
# This profile class installs the BookingsUI package from a URI specified in the global ::package_source variable
class phoenix_profiles::archive_test {
  $archive_file        = "BookingsUI.zip"
  $drive               = pick($::destination_drive, 'd:')
  # $staged_archive_path = "${drive}/eftours/packages/${archive_file}"
  $staged_archive_path = "${drive}/temp/puppet_archive_test/source/${archive_file}"
  dsc_xremotefile { "download ${archive_file}":
    dsc_uri => "${::package_source}/${archive_file}",
    dsc_destinationpath => $staged_archive_path
  } ->
  dsc_archive { "unpack ${archive_file}":
    dsc_ensure      => 'Present',
    dsc_validate    => "true",
    dsc_checksum    => "ModifiedDate",
    dsc_force       => "true",
    dsc_path        => $staged_archive_path,
    dsc_destination => "${drive}/temp/puppet_archive_test/BookingsUI"
  }
}
```

NOTE: This is cross-posted from: http://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/16423/is-the-file-currentmof-a-bottleneck-when-using-the-dsc-module/

Comment: Can you give us any of the output from when things "go screwy?" I for one would like to see what you're describing about executing the wrong MOF.

Comment: I agree about seeing the output. Plus it may help to followup with an issue on the module source itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. You may want to file an issue here https://github.com/msutter/puppet-dsc

**Update:** I filed an issue at https://github.com/msutter/puppet-dsc/issues/1

Comment: Thank you. I tested it and if I explicitly order all my resources, this problem disappears.